# ¿Qué entendéis por optimizar el espacio utilizado en Python trabajando con un fichero csv?

Tags: python, array, pandas, csv, numpy

Estoy haciendo un trabajo de un master y un ejercicio de Python me pide eso, OPTIMIZAR EL ESPACIO UTILIZADO.

Se me da un fichero .csv y he de trabajar con el. Hacer varias operaciones que van desde calcular mean o median . No os aburro. Y más operaciones que por lo que veo son matemáticas.

Estoy empezando con Python. Solo he leído el manual  y no entero).
Parece ser que trabajar con array y numpy es lo que yo entiendo , da un resultado optimo.
Pero....

¿ es eso?

¿ como optimizar el espacio utilizado según tu opinión en Python ?

Gracias

nota:  Ya se a que se refieren con optimizar. Es espacio en memoria. No usar Float donde es posible usar un integer positivo que ocupa menos espacio.

Ahora quiero cambiar un objeto, que es fecha con el formato de abajo.

0       13/10/2020
1        9/10/2020
2        6/10/2020
3        2/10/2020
4       29/09/2020

Ocupa un espacio en memoria que es posible reducir cambiando el objeto a otro tipo. Para ello necesito leer la fecha. En eso estoy ahora, aprendiendo a leer de ese objeto , un dato, por ejemplo el mes.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Me parecía interesante poner esa pregunta. Mi fichero de aprendizaje es una nadería. Pero como sabeis mejor que yo, trabajáis con tablas y ficheros inmensos, el tamaño SI importa.

;-)

Gracias

Comment: Creo que lo mejor sería preguntarle a quién te dejó el trabajo. Puedes optimizar un código de muchas maneras, con "espacio utilizado" podrían referirse a líneas de código o tamaño del archivo de python (esto es común también en trabajos para facilitar la revisión de los mismos). En fin, las preguntas que se basan en opiniones no son bien recibidas y generalmente terminan cerradas.

Comment: Entiendo lo siguiente: al procesar un archivo, muchos ingenuamente lo cargan completo en una lista antes de procesarlo. Eso ocupa tanta memoria como tan grande sea el archivo. Optimizar el espacio, en este contexto, significa leer y procesar de a una línea a la vez. Así el espacio ocupado es mínimo: una línea más las variables de tu proceso.

Comment: Al hablar de *espacio optimizado* se me viene a la cabeza como a cualquier programador, el uso de RAM que genera el código. Sin embargo si acabas de empezar y estás aprediendo cálculos básicos, dudo mucho que te pidan hacer esto. Creo que se refiere a que para esos cálculos utilices la menor cantidad de lineas de código que puedas.

Comment: Se refiere a:  tenemos números entre 1 y 20. Por tanto, podemos representarlos usando menos información. Para ello, usamos el método to_numeric de pandas y el atributo downcast="unsigned" para especificar números sin signo (ya que todos son positivos). Convertimos las columnas que contienen enteros y vemos el resultado.

El método to_numeric con el atributo downcast permite almacenar un número en el tipo más pequeño posible.

Si tuviésemos números positivos y negativos, usaríamos la opción integer.